# How to switch to the design view in VC++ 2012?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012

I have just installed Visual Studio 2012 Professional Edition and I'm planning to write my first Hello World application but I can't find the designer view !

[image]

How can I switch to the designer mode in Visual C++ 2012 Professional?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe you are used to C#, where when you have let's say `MyForm.cs` and you just open it, it opens `MyForm.cs [Design]` window by default, in which you can design your dialog.

In Visual C++, the appearance of the dialog is stored in the resource file, thus you need to double click on `Win32Project3.rc` which will switch your left pane to the **Resource view**. Then you will see more resource types (they look like folders) and under **Dialog** you will find your dialog.

Comment: I can see only the about dialog, Where is the main dialog with white background ?

Comment: @ShikataGaNai: There can be more dialogs defined within one resource file. Also there can be more resource files... you just need to find the right dialog :)

Answer (score 1):

I found that double-clicking the header file (as shown in the Solution Explorer) opens designer view where applicable. To get the actual template, I used an online template through VS2015. Sorry if this response isn't the best, I just got a hang of it earlier today...